# CSS-Friendly Menu adapter that emits the same markup as .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, css, menu

For .NET 2.x/3.x there exists a CSS-Friendly Adapter on CodePlex that emits markup for an ASP.NET Menu Control as an ul.

The .NET 4.0 Menu control will also emit an ul, but the CSS class names are different from those emitted by the CSS-Friendly Adapter 1.0 on CodePlex.

In the interests of having a single version of CSS for .NET 2/3/4 sites, I want to create a version of the CSS-Friendly menu adapter that emits the same markup as the .NET 4.0 Menu control.

Before doing so, I thought I'd ask here to see if it's already been done, so I don't reinvent the wheel.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented my own MenuAdapter that renders a static menu with CSS classes compatible with the default rendering of the .NET 4.0 Menu control - this is fairly simple to implement.

I can see it would be complex to implement an adapter that is fully compatible with the .NET 4.0 control, as it would need to include the .NET 4.0 script for dynamic menus.  Which presumably explains why no-one has (yet) done so.